# Username not showing in Chrome "Update Password"

Tags: google-chrome

When I fill out my signup form, I enter a username, then click "Suggest strong Password" for the password box.

The username doesn't show in this box. How can I force it to? Here are my username and password fields.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="" placeholder="" required="" autocomplete="username"><br><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="uPass" id="uPass" required="" autocomplete="new-password"><br><br>

  Confirm: <input type="password" name="uPass_2" id="uPass_2" required="" autocomplete="new-password"><br><br>
 
  <button type="submit">
   Create
  </button>
</form>
```

[image]

Below is a JS Fiddle, SO's code playground wouldn't even give me a password list. I guess it's a difference in how they render the page.

### First, here's how to reproduce the issue:

Enter a username, say "stack".

Click the first password field, click "suggest strong password." Nothing will happen because it's the first time you're saving a password to that username.

Rerun the fiddle, enter the same username, click "suggest strong password." again. This time, you'll get the popup because you're actually updating the password.

### JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gn1qzwyu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password along with username is normally saved and updated on a redirect. In that case the username is picked up correctly. However, in case of "suggest password" the password is actually remembered in advance, during this action, not during redirect. Because of your fiddle does not provide correct redirect, after first "suggest password" attempt, credentials are saved as a password with "no username".

This "no username" is the reason for immediate pop-up during second "suggest password" attempt because Chrome can't decide which username is correct - "no username" or that one you filled up in the form. Note that second, "correct one" is pickable in the "Username" field too - its triangle is visible on your screenshot. The reason for immediate pop-up is the same as it was for first attempt - Chrome wants to save suggested password in advance and does not wait a redirect. The reason why Chrome remembers suggested password right away and doesn't remember username in the same moment is that suggested password is trusted upon form submission but the username is not.

It seems like Edge and Firefox have the same behavior.

Solution for productive sites: implicitly provide correct redirect (or substitutive actions). Solution for users: delete saved credentials with blank username for that sites where a username should exist.